# Vertically Centred Text inside window height variable div

Tags: html, css

So I want to be able to centre all my content inside a particular div. The div in question has a 'height: 100vh; attribute to enable it to fit the height of the viewers window.. you can view it at http://digitalsix.hostzi.com/

What i'm looking at being able to do is center the content at all times, including when the window has been resized (i realise once it gets too small theres not much that can be done. An example of what im looking for is http://www.pixelbeach.co.uk/

I just cant seem to find the way to do it. If anyone could help that would be great.

Markup:

```css
#screenfiller{
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(topbar_1.jpg);
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
    <div id="screenfiller">
    <header>
    <a href="#"><img alt="Digital Six Creative" src="logo.svg"></a>
    </header>

    <p><a href="#location" class="button_med_white_o">TEST BUTTON</a></p>

        </div>
    </div>
    <a name="about"></a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the content in a container div, and do:

```
.container{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

Or:

```
#screenfiller{
  ...
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}

.container{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

To take the header into account, change your `#screenfiller` height property to `height: calc(100vh - 340px);` where 340px is the height of your header.

Comment: The first solution is something I have tried and has come closest to what I'm looking for but using relative positioning rather than absolute. However with those percentage values, or any, it doesn't seem to be centred.. I have reuploaded the site using what I have thats similar if you take a look at: http://digitalsix.hostzi.com/

new CSS is as follows with .screen_container acting as the container for the content:

.screen_container{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check your site before posting. What are you aiming to do, get the button vertical inside the image? If you change to absolute positioning, it does centre within the viewport, although it conflicts with your design.

Comment: Yes, I want the button (or any content i put in there) to be vertically centred. I've now managed to get the content centred inside the div i want, but It seems to me that the problem is that the #screenfiller div that has the attribute height: 100vh; isn't able to offset the size of the header with the logo and nav bar inside. I have reuploaded again to show what i mean: digitalsix.hostzi.com

Comment: If your header is a fixed height, and you are only bothered about newer browsers, you could set `height: calc(100vh - header_height);`

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get this to work at all... There is no set height for the header.

Comment: I just checked the height of your header and it's 340px. You could give it a static value, or use JavaScript to set it.

Comment: Scrap that... i just gave the header a fixed height and have managed to get it working. thanks

Comment: Can you accept the answer if the problem is sorted now? Thanks